# Formtastic Nesting Help

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I'm trying to familiarize myself with the following situation.

routine.rb

```
class Routine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exercise_routines
  has_many :exercises, :through => :exercise_routines
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercise_routines
end
```

exercise_routine.rb

```
class ExerciseRoutine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exercise
  belongs_to :routine
  has_many :attempts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attempts
end
```

show.html #/routines/show.html.haml

```
%h2 Exercises:

%ol
  - for exercise_routine in @routine.exercise_routines
    %li= exercise_routine.exercise.name
    %ul
      %li
        = exercise_routine.sets
        Sets
      %li
        = exercise_routine.reps
        Reps
      %li
        Attempt: 
        - for attempt in exercise_routine.attempts
          = attempt.reps
        = semantic_form_for @routine do |routine|
          = routine.semantic_fields_for exercise_routine do |exercise_routine|
            = exercise_routine.semantic_fields_for :attempts do |attempt|
              = attempt.input :reps, :required => false
          = routine.buttons`
```

What I'm having trouble with is two things:
1) This is successfully rendering attempts for each routine if I manually add it through the console but if I try to update it I'll get: "unknown attribute: exercise_routine" and I realize that because the params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"51fZRe1wKRQoVUz+lGlldd4DmMODGHN203Htc4DEi0Y=",
 "routine"=>{"exercise_routine"=>{"attempts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"reps"=>"5",
 "id"=>"1"},
 "1"=>{"reps"=>"1555",
 "id"=>"2"},
 "2"=>{"reps"=>""}}}},
 "commit"=>"Update Routine",
"id"=>"3"}`
```

Don't look right. It should reference exercise_routines with an id.

2) Want to be able to add an attempt at the same time.

```
@routine.exercise_routines.each do |er|
  1.times {er.attempts.build}
end
```

Renders it properly but of course I'm running into the same params problem. I'm either doing something stupidly wrong, or this is harder than I think to do this type of multiple collection nesting?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using `fields_for` properly. The first argument has to the association to use for the nested fields. The second one then can be a collection of/single model(s) to use for the value of the association.

```
= routine.semantic_fields_for :exercise_routines, exercise_routine do |f|
```

Also I would suggest not hiding the first local `exercise_routine` with the form builder local inside the block. And I would use the `@routine.exercise_routines.each do |exercise_routine|` form instead of the `for` loop.